# Rust how to implement trait of convert string to vec function?

Tags: rust

I have got a problem with implement the convert string to vec function with trait.

Here is the error message:

```
error[E0277]: a value of type `Result<_, _>` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `char`
    --> src/main.rs:7:28
     |
7    |         match self.chars().collect() {
     |                            ^^^^^^^ value of type `Result<_, _>` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=char>`
     |
     = help: the trait `FromIterator<char>` is not implemented for `Result<_, _>`
     = help: the trait `FromIterator<Result<_, _>>` is implemented for `Result<_, _>`
     = help: for that trait implementation, expected `Result<_, _>`, found `char`
note: the method call chain might not have had the expected associated types
    --> src/main.rs:7:20
     |
7    |         match self.chars().collect() {
     |               ---- ^^^^^^^ `Iterator::Item` is `char` here
     |               |
     |               this expression has type `&&str`
note: required by a bound in `collect`
    --> /playground/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/iter/traits/iterator.rs:2050:19
     |
2050 |     fn collect<B: FromIterator<Self::Item>>(self) -> B
     |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `Iterator::collect`
```

And the code as below:

```
trait StringObject {
    fn convert_to_vec(&self) -> Result<Vec<char>,&'static str>;
}

impl StringObject for &str {
    fn convert_to_vec(&self) -> Result<Vec<char>, &'static str> {
        match self.chars().collect() {
            Ok(c) => Ok(c),
            Err(e) => Err(e),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let sobje = "teststringe";
    let array:Vec<char> = sobje.chars().collect();
    // let sobjechars = sobje.convert_to_vec().unwrap();
    println!("sobjechars={:?}",array);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chars()` of a `&str` has no error conditions whatsoever, it's elements are `char`, so you can just `collect` into a `Vec<char>` directly and wrap it in `Ok`:

```rust
impl StringObject for &str {
    fn convert_to_vec(&self) -> Result<Vec<char>, &'static str> {
        Ok(self.chars().collect())
    }
}
```

To collect into a `Result` and match on `Ok` or `Err` the items of an iterator have to be `Result`s themselves.